# Assigning materials using nodes

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm using **Blender 2.7**,and I want to assign a material to a particular part of an object, and for some reason I'm only able to use nodes for this, and normal assigning wasn't working for me.How do I use nodes to assign materials?

Comment: Your use of the terminology is not clear. Nodes are the workflow inside a material. Add a new Material slot, select the Faces that define the part of the Mesh you want to affect and click Assign.Edit your question if that does not help and add screenshots.

Comment: Well, infact, my problem is that when I assign my material to my mesh, all I get is that part of the mesh being a White, diffuse material rather than what I want ( Red, Glossy).I also have this feeling that only nodes can fix it because as I change the nodes, the material color is getting affected.

Comment: I still votes screenshots. Show what works, what does not and what you want the result to be. We will be happy to help.